# How to generate header and footer across all the pages of HTML generated PDF file?

Tags: python, html, html-to-pdf, weasyprint

While trying to generate a PDF file using HTML template, Weasyprint and Python, I am unable to generate a common header a footer across all the pages of the file. Is there a way to populate header and footer in all the pages without using Javascript or JQuery